# Why are my planned values for tasks so high when employees not working 8 hours?

Tags: ms-project, scheduling

I have assigned 5 resources for a task. MS Project assumes that all resources are available to work 8 hours per day 5 days per week. This is not the case in my schedule. Some of the resources work maybe 2 hours per day and then zero hours the next day but will finish the task by the finish date.

I'm just looking to track actual hours compared to budgeted hours and also do an earned value analysis. My planned values for each task are way too high and I can't do an accurate analysis if the resources are scheduled for full time work.

Answer (score 1):

Yo have to specify availability of resources while assigning.
i have one task with 2 days duration and 2 Resources are assigned. in this case MS project assumes 2 Resources are working full time ( 8 hrs /day) and total effort for that task is 16x2= 32 Hrs.

In above situation,i have resources working part time ( 4 hrs/day), this needs to be informed in such a way that either while assigning resources, specify ( % loading against each resource).

1 Resource- 50%
2 Resource- 30%
in this case total effort for task is ( 4 hrs for 1st Resource and 2.4 hrs for second resource)-12.8 hrs for Two days.
Above can be implemented through each resource calendar by defining working hours at calendar level and same can be specified in task information.